# How to "inject" style in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate

I am trying to separate the DataTemplates from the Styles in my code. 
I use DataTemplate to define, e.g. that the data should be displayed as two buttons and I use styles to define, e.g. that the background of those buttons should be green.

What I am trying to achieve is having a DataTemplate defined in one file and using that in multiple `UserControl`s where the style comes from the `UserControl`s.

Let's say I have the following style in the `Resources` of a `UserControl`:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Another `UserControl` might have something similar with different colors.

Then, I have a `ContentControl` in that `UserControl` that will have some view model and some DataTemplate:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"
                ContentTemplate="{Binding SelectedDataTemplate}"/>
```

The DataTemplate can be something as simple as this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TwoButtonsTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="One"/>
        <Button Content="Two"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like the two buttons to have the `ButtonStyle` from the `UserControl.Resources` without directly referencing it. (So the DataTemplate can come from a different file or being able to use the DataTemplate in a similar context with another `UserControl`'s style).

I tried to change the `TargetType` of `ButtonStyle` to `ContentControl`, assign the style to the `ContentControl` and set `Foreground="{TemplatedParent Foreground}"` on the `Button`s, but in this way both `Foreground` will change when any of them (i.e. the `ContentControl` itself) is hovered.

Is there any way of "inheriting" a style in the DataTemplate or "injecting" the style from the `UserControl`?

P.S. I understand if I move the style into a separate file and reference that in the DataTemplate file I can simply use it as `StaticResource`, but that will couple the DataTemplate to that specific style and I won't be able to re-use it with other styles.

Comment: try DynamicResource: `<Button Content="One" Style="{DynamicResource}"/>`

Comment: That seems to work (with an actual key). Do you know if DynamicResource has any performance overhead?

Comment: it is negligible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try DynamicResource:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TwoButtonsTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="One" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Content="Two" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

when TwoButtonsTemplate template is instantiated in UserControl, which declares ButtonStyle resource, that resource will be found and applied to buttons.